# Angular & NGRX prevent selector from emitting identical value on state change when values are equal

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm searching for a solution to make my selector only emit a new value when the it has changed compared to the last emitted value, and not only the reference to the store is changed.

I have the following state in my store:

```
{
   items: [],
   loading: false,
   selectedItemId: 1
}
```

And I have the following selector:

```
export const getSelectedItem = createSelector(getItemsState,
    (state) => {
        return state.selectedItemId === null ? null : state.items.find(item => item.id === state.selectedItemId)
    }
);
```

When I do a subscribe on this selector this fires each time when for example the loading flag in the store changes. I would like the selector to emit only a value when the value of the selected item has changed. I.e. from 1 to 2. But not when the reference of the state object is different.

I found one solution for my problem with doing this:

```
this.itemStore.select(getSelectedItem).distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => {
    return x.id === y.id;
}).subscribe(item => {
    // do something
});
```

However, I would like to move the logic to make the updated distinct into my selector instead of having this on the calling side.

I understand why I have this behavior as the framework only checks for object equality and the store reference changes as we return a new ItemState object from the reducer each time something changes in there. But I’m unable to find a solution to my problem, and I cannot imagine that I’m the only person in need of a selector which updates only when the effective value has been changed.

The code for the reducer looks like this:

```
export function itemsReducer(state: ItemsState = initialItemsState, action: Action): ItemsState {
    switch(action.type) {
        case itemActions.ITEMS_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                itemsLoading: true
            };
        case itemActions.ITEMS_LOAD_SUCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload,
                itemsLoading: false
            };
        // ... a lot of other similar actions
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your reducer where you update (e.g.) the loading flag? If you keep the same object for the detail while updating the loading flag elsewhere in the state, it should just work, I would think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With your current reducer, `distinctUntilChanged` is the correct operator to handle this. Another way to address this would be by making your reducer detect whether the object is "functionally unchanged" when updating the items, for example, something like:

```
export function itemsReducer(state: ItemsState = initialItemsState, action: Action): ItemsState {
    switch(action.type) {
        case itemActions.ITEMS_LOAD:
            return {
                ...state,
                itemsLoading: true
            };
        case itemActions.ITEMS_LOAD_SUCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload.map((newItem) => {
                   let oldItem = state.items.find((i) => i.id == newItem.id);
                   // If the item exists in the old state, and is deeply-equal
                   // to the new item, return the old item so things watching it
                   // know they won't need to update.
                   if (oldItem && itemEqual(newItem, oldItem)) return oldItem;

                   // Otherwise, return the newItem as either there was no old
                   // item, or the newItem is materially different to the old.
                   return newItem;
                }),
                itemsLoading: false
            };
        // ... a lot of other similar actions
    }
}
```

You would need to implement itemEqual somehow to check for deep logical equality. This is where you use your knowledge of what, functionally, "equal" means to decide whether the item has changed, for example:

```
function itemEqual(item1, item2) {
    // Need here to do a /deep/ equality check between 
    // the two items, e.g.:
    return (item1.id == item2.id && 
           item1.propertyA == item2.propertyA &&
           item1.propertyB == item2.propertyB)
}
```

You could use something like lodash's `_.isEqual()` function instead of implementing your own `itemEqual` for a general deep equality check on the objects.

Comment: I was testing it again yesterday and so far it did not yet solve my problem, but I was planing some additional test today. As my actual use case is a bit bigger than what I have posted.

Comment: So did my further tests now. And this actually solves my problem. I had a conceptual misunderstanding on how ngrx does detect state change. And if I actually only update the state when we have a change then I don't get the selector emitting anything when it should not.

Answer (score 2):

Add a check in your reducer, which checks the current state. and the payload. if the payload value is identical to your current state, do not override the state. but return the current state as it is. and your reducer will fire only if the values and reference is indeed changed.

like:

```
case 'XXXSTATE':  
if(state.xxx.value === payload.value)
       return state; 
else 
       return {...state,itemsLoading: true};
```

Also redux not only checks for references, but that is an another topic :)

Comment: > Also redux not only checks for references, but that is an another topic :)
Do you have a link to a source/ further explanation for this? Because I understood this differently so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are returning the same value back.
To trigger change you have to return a new object not a reference to existing value.

```
return state.selectedItemId === null ? null : Object.assign({}, state.items.find(item => item.id === state.selectedItemId))
```