# NgRx selector emits when anything on the state changes/memoization of selector not working

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using Angular 7 along with NgRx. I have created a selector to get some data from the store using `filter`, but this selector emits when anything on the store changes, even if it is not related to my selector.

I have created a demonstration of my issue. Here is my selector:

```
export const getMyArrayFilter = createSelector(
    getCounterState,
    state => state.myArray.filter(x => x === 'new Item')
);
```

And here I am using my `getMyArrayFilter` selector:

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getMyArrayFilter)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

But as mentioned, this `selector` will emit anytime anything changes on the state.

Please take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-selector-props-58hqib) StackBlitz demonstration.

If you try clicking on either the "Add item to array" or "-" or "+" buttons, then my `getMyArrayFilter` will emit, and log to the console each time. Should't my selector only emit values IF the `myArray` on my state changes?

I have taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51961413/angular-ngrx-prevent-selector-from-emitting-identical-value-on-state-change-wh) SOF question which mentions using `distinctUntilChanged` but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: That is normal selector will emit new value when there is any change in the store. I dont understand what is your problem here

Comment: @TonyNgo shouldn't my selector only emit values if `myArray` changes on my state?

Comment: Selector will emit value when there is any change. In your code you call 3 times to `fromRoot.getCount()` so it will return 3 times data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Alejandro pointed out, this is because there's a new reference for `myArray`.
You can modify the memoization to your needs, Alex Okrushko does exactly this in his talk [NgRx: Selectors are more powerful than you think](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7GKnjGCXzU&t=641s)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Doing some testing with your example I just notice that ngrx compare the arrays by reference and not by every item inside of it, what this means is that since the function filter return a new array with a new reference ngrx thinks that is different and that is why the subscribe is called every time something changes.

Creating a new copy will have the same effect:

```js
export const getMyArrayFilter = createSelector(
    getCounterState,
    state => [ ...state.myArray ]
);
```